# Tomcat authentication with request headers

Tags: tomcat, servlets, authentication, passwords, jdbcrealm

I have a web app running on Tomcat 7. Currently users login with passwords through JDBCRealm.

In my organization there's an authentication server. Users send HTTP requests to that server, the server authenticates them somehow, and then forwards the request to my app with a custom HTTP header that specifies the authenticated username (no password).

I'd like to use this mechanism for authenticating users to my app, while keeping the JDBC realm. When users send a request to `/login`, their request will be authenticated using the headers, and they'll be redirected to the main page as if they logged in using the standard `j_security_check` form, but without having to provide a password.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
@WebFilter("/login/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    String username = ... // Extract username from httpRequest, not an issue

    httpRequest.login(username, "???"); // Need to provide a password!

    httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/pages/home.xhtml");

  }

}
```

This works when I provide the right password for JDBCRealm, but the password is unavailable in the filter.

**Update:** I ended up solving this with a custom valve:

```
public class LoginValve extends ValveBase {

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request req, Response res) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (!req.getRequestURI().equals(req.getContextPath() + "/login")) {
        getNext().invoke(req, res);
        return;
    }

    Session session = req.getSessionInternal();

    if (session.getPrincipal() == null) {
        String username = ... // From req
        List<String> roles = ... // From req
        session.setPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(username, null, roles));
    }

    req.setUserPrincipal(session.getPrincipal());

    getNext().invoke(req, res);

}
```

And I do the redirect from a filter that's called later.

Comment: Just get it from same user DB as realm is using?

Comment: The password is hashed in the DB, plus it seems like a waste of resources as I don't really need the password, I just want to set the user as logged in.

Comment: Then configure realm to not hash it once more.

Comment: I can't save passwords in plaintext

Comment: So user registration happens via same realm? This is quite unexpected as you apparently have a separate authentication server. Well, just add another realm which doesn't hash passwords and will be used as a read-only realm so you can login with an already hashed password.

Comment: @liadmat Please split that "update" content into an answer of your own. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm three reputation points shy of being able to comment, so I'll have to answer based on the given information, filling in some of the blanks with guesses.

You can achieve the "authentication" by subclassing [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

Override the getRemoteUser() and getUserPrincipal() so they return the authenticated user's username, and a Principal object that can be basically anything you want to make it. A [JMXPrincipal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXPrincipal.html) should be convenient to use. You should probably also override getAuthType() to return HttpServletRequest.FORM_AUTH to make everything mesh nicely. And implement a quick logout() method per the Javadoc, which says "Establish null as the value returned when getUserPrincipal, getRemoteUser, and getAuthType is called on the request."

Then, in your filter, wrap the incoming HttpServletRequest in your wrapper object, and pass the wrapper object into chain.doFilter().

If you want to get fancy you can override the login() method also on the wrapper, where it accepts any (or a null) password and creates the internal instance variables that will be returned by getRemoteUser(), getUserPrincipal() and getAuthType().

Comment: I've subclassed HttpServletRequestWrapper, and when the filter is set to @WebFilter("/*") then your solution seems to work. However when I set it to @WebFilter("/login/*"), I get a "resource not found" error, because there's nothing there after chain.doFilter. I need to somehow redirect the new request to "/pages/home.xhtml", but sendRedirect doesn't take a request argument like doFilter. I also tried using getRequestDispatcher(...).forward(...), the initial redirect works and the user is logged in, but all following AJAX requests seem to be broken.

Comment: I don't know if this could be the cause of the failing AJAX, but I noticed something strange: on every XHR the server responds with a new JSESSIONID cookie, even though the filter is only called once

Comment: Thanks to whoever upvoted my answer. It put me over the threshold for commenting.

Comment: @liad, the JSESSIONID cookie issue leads me to ask, are all the requests, including XHR, images, etc., going through the authentication server in reverse-proxy fashion, or just some? Or is the authentication server using 302 responses to redirect requests to the app server?

Comment: Remember that the sesson cookies are associated with the host name. Since the authentication server is inserting a request header, I assume that means that the session cookie (at least from the authentication request) is associated with the host name of the authentication server. Any subsequent requests that don't go through the authentication server will not have the correct session cookie.

When you say that a new JSESSIONID cookie is set with each XHR response, that suggests the requests are not sending up any JSESSIONID cookie? If not, why not?

Comment: You're right, we're using a reverse proxy for all the requests. But for now, in order to test everything, I'm not using the authentication server, I'm sending requests directly to the application server (without extracting the username from the headers, it's temporarily hard-coded). Requests are sent with a JSESSIONID, but every time the server ignores it and sends a new cookie (Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=...). The client then sends the next request with the new cookie, and the server overwrites it again... It seems that the standard HttpServletRequest.login method does something that I'm missing

Comment: I've made a mistake in my first comment, setting the filter to @WebFilter("/*") doesn't work either

Comment: Until you figure out the problem with the JSESSIONID cookie, everything else is moot. I suggest you post a new question for that, along with all of the information someone would need to troubleshoot it.